# ¿Pasar función con argumentos a otro componente ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Soy nuevo usando reactjs estoy haciendo un componente y me acaba de surgir un problema espero ser claro y me puedan ayudar.

Tengo un componente que muestra un modal y recibe 3 parámetros.

1. text- String
2. btn1- {text, function}
3. btn2- {text, function}

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Modal extends React.Component {

render(){
return(
<div className="modal fade show" style={{ display: 'block' }} role="dialog">
 <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div className="modal-content">
   <div className="modal-header">
     <h5 className="modal-title">Alerta</h5>
   </div>
   <div className="modal-body">
     <p>{this.props.text}</p>
   </div>
   <div className="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.btn1.function}>{this.props.btn1.text}</button>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.btn2.function}>{this.props.btn2.text}</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
);
}
}

export default Modal;
```

Este componente lo llamo desde otro componente, con el siguiente código

```
let btn1 = { text: "No", function: this.closeModalWarning }
let btn2 = { text: "Si", function: this.deleteImage(1) }

this.openModal("¿Desea eliminar?",btn1, btn2);

openModal(text, btn1, btn2){
   <Modal text={text} btn1={btn1}, btn2={btn2} />
}

deleteImage = (index) => {
   console.log(index);
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando aparece el dialog la función `deleteImage` se ejecuta y cuando hago clic en el botón de si no pasa nada.

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te diria que empezaras por no usar palabras reservadas del lenguage para nombrar tus variables, me refiero a `function`. Y el error que te da es porque estás ejecutando  function: this.deleteImage(1).

Para que esto te vaya bien, la function deleteImage haz que devuelva otra funcion y listo.

```js
deleteImage = (index) => () => {
   console.log(index);
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu comentario lo tendré en cuenta, gracias.